# Pusher : No callbacks on testChannel for App\Events\Event

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, pusher

I built a Laravel broadcasting, planning to implement this as a live-chat App. When checking on the client-side page, the console log shows:

> Pusher : Event recd :
>   `{"event":"App\\Events\\Event","data":{"message":"Greetings from
>   PrinceLuo!"},"channel":"testChannel"}`
>
> Pusher : No callbacks on testChannel for App\Events\Event

It just ignores the callback function which does exists......

By the way, I have not yet install npm so I was using the simple Javascript code suggested by the Pusher dashboard, instead of the Vue code suggested by Laravel.

Both on the console log and the Pusher dashboard I can see the broadcasting message sent by the server.

Here is my client-side code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Pusher Test</title>

  <script src="{{ asset('js/pusher.min.js') }}"></script>
  <script>

    // Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
    Pusher.logToConsole = true;

    var pusher = new Pusher('****************', {
      cluster: 'ap1',
      encrypted: true
    });

    var channel = pusher.subscribe('testChannel');
    channel.bind('App\Events\Event', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});


  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Pusher Test</h1>
  <p>
    Try publishing an event to channel <code>testChannel</code>
    with event name <code>Event</code>.
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Just simply hide the pusher key~~

I have googled some similar cases. But no one could give me answer.
Anyone has met this case or has any ideas on this case?

---

**UPDATE:**

I also post my server-side code here for anyone needed:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class Event implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        //
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
//        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
//        return new PrivateChannel('testChannel');
        return new \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel('testChannel');
    }
}
```

And here is my route:

```
Route::get('test_event',function(){
    event(new Event('Greetings from PrinceLuo!'));
});

Route::get('test_listen',function(){
    return view('listenBroadcast');
});
```

Comment: Could you share your server code that publishes the event too please?

Comment: @Will Sewell   Sure, please check the question updated.

Comment: It does look ok... What happens if you us [`bind_global`](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js#bind_global-and-unbind_global)? I'm concerned that the event name might not be correct.

Comment: The event App\Events\Event was triggered with data [object Object]
pusher.min.js:8 Pusher : No callbacks on testChannel for App\Events\Event     That's all it show. Still not working

Comment: actually, I cooperate with one of my colleague, testing this push on the android app. And the android app received and decompose the message correctly. Something wrong in the javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who interesting this case, I post what I have done for solving this question:

Pay attention that the Push Logger shows 【App\Events\Event】 to escape the function of the back slash. So in the JavaScript, we have to change it the same:

```
channel.bind('App\\Events\\Event', function(data){});
```

Simple but essential.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did

```
channel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function(members) {
    // alert('successfully subscribed!');
 });

 channel.bind("App\\Events\\NewComment", function(data) {
     console.log(data);
 });
```